# Extrair valores de uma string em javascript

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Tenho uma página que apresenta informações através de `AJAX`. Cada vez que eu faço uma pesquisa, tenho o valor da pesquisa e página no `URL`, da seguinte forma:

> /Material/Index??palavraChave??numPagina

Eu consigo buscar esses valores através do `.split("??")`, mas queria implementar algo mais intuitivo:

> /Material/Index?qw=palavraChave&pag=numPagina

Como faço para guardar numa variável só a **palavraChave** e noutra a **numPagina** e o mais importante: a palavra chave pode faltar, mas ter o número da página. Com os pontos de interrogação que eu tenho não consigo saber se o que tenho no `URL` é um valor para pesquisa, ou uma página.

Comment: Como está seu ajax para criar essa URl?

Comment: Não uso ajax para criar a url, estou a usar pushState() e passo as variáves que o utilizador introduzir numa caixa de pesquisa,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você trabalha com uma string pequena e tem um padrão. pode tentar utilizar regex.

```
qw=([A-Za-z0-9]+)&pag=([0-9]+)
```

onde o que se encontra entre parênteses são os grupos que são importantes para você.

[exemplo do seu caso](https://regex101.com/r/xrkOXW/1)

Comment: consegui perfeitamente usando essa técnica, obrigado! regex é muito bom!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [location.search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) que irá retornar de `?` até o final da URL. Então depois tratar o resultado.

Exemplo para o seu caso:

```
var url = window.location.search; // retorno será algo como: '?qw=palavraChave&pag=numPagin';
var campos = url.split('=');
```

**Simulação do tratamento:**

```js
var url = window.location.search; // retorno será algo como: '?qw=palavraChave&pag=numPagin';
var resExamplo = '?qw=stackoverflow&pag=10';
var campos = resExamplo.split('=')[2]; // obter o numero da pagina
console.log(campos);
```

Comment: O problema desse código é parecido ao meu: se não houver uma keyword de pesquisa então ele vai assumir que a página é a keyword. Queria algo que "soubesse" identificar cada variável.

Comment: "ele vai assumir que a página é a keyword". Não tem mágica para obter os parâmetros de uma URL, você vai precisar obter a URL de alguma forma e verificar o que está nela. No exemplo de tratamento, é possível "saber" cada variável, tanto o nome como o valor.

Comment: eu sei que não tem mágica, mas descobri que existe regex. Mas com essa técnica que você colocou é possível "saber" qual é qual de que forma?